# Why use "need not" instead of "do not need to"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, negation, modal-verbs, semi-modals

The header of [psyco.sourceforge.net](http://psyco.sourceforge.net) states:

> High-level languages need not be slower than low-level ones.

Why use *need not* instead of *do not need*? What does it mean? Also, why no *to* before *be*?

Comment: also consider *Brevity* in the artful construction of language

Comment: *Need not* sounds more refined and formal.

Comment: This is subjuncitve mood. You can read this: https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subjunctive.html

Comment: @martinkunev That is incorrect. Those constructions are different (and some would say shouldn't be called 'subjunctive' anyway).  Read Cerberus's correct explanation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What reason do you have to believe that this is not subjunctive mood?

Comment: As Cerberus says, it's a usage of the modal 'need' (followed by the infinitive 'be'). 'You need not be present.' Compare 'You need not go.' / 'You must not be present.' You're confusing this with old-fashioned  usages such as 'I insist that he be replaced.' (= 'I insist that he should / must be replaced.')

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two verbs *need*, which mean the same thing but use different constructions:

> 1.
>
> He **need** not be concerned.
>
> **Need** I be concerned?

This *need* is sometimes called a **modal verb** (although others find this term inconsistent): it always requires an infinitive without *to*; it doesn't have *do-support* in questions and negative sentences; and the third person singular (he/she/it) doesn't have *-s*. This is the *need* in your example. It is of the same type as *must, will, shall, can, may, help*, and probably a few uncommon cases.

Modal *need* is slightly old fashioned. Except in negative sentences and questions, it is less common in modern writing, except perhaps in certain fixed expressions (though the *need* in *if need be* is a noun).

---

> 2.
>
> He **doesn't need to** call her.
>
> **Do** I **need to** call him?
>
> She **needs to** call him.
>
> You **need** him.

This is the more common *need*, a **regular verb** (no 'modal'). If it is used with another verb, the infinitive with *to* is used. It always has *do-support*. It can be used without another verb, with a direct object (*you need him*).

Comment: Blast, you beat me to it.  The Wiktionary entry for [need](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/need) has some handy usage notes that explain a few more forms of the word.

Comment: @Rhodri: Hah, you lo—I mean, my apologies!

Comment: +1 It doesn't seem that old-fashioned in the negative. Google Ngrams shows "need not" is still used [much more often](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=need%20not%2Cneeds%20not%2Cdoes%20not%20need%20to%2Cdoesn%20%27%20t%20need%20to&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000) than either "needs not" and "does not need to". For the regular verb, you can see from the Ngram that "does not need to" is slowly replacing "needs not".

Comment: @Peter Shor: *Need* is also a noun.  With that ngram, you have no way of excluding things like "there is a need not to generalize".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I checked a sample, and the vast majority indeed seem to be *need* being used as a modal verb.

Comment: @Peter Shor: If you have to browse through results to conclude that it *seems* to be used that way, then is the graph really worth anything?

Comment: If you put a "He" (capitalized so it goes at the beginning of a sentence) in the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+need+not%2CHe+needs+not%2CHe+doesn%27t+need+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) you get nearly the same results. I don't see how there could be any false positives in this set.

Comment: Great, now I need no longer have a bad conscience when writing phrases like "does not and need not compute ...." ;)

Comment: Historical note: "need not" replaced ["tharf not"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tharf) during Middle English. The verb *tharf* was also a modal used only in the negative, and is cognate with the German modal verb *dürfen*, meaning *must*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Damn, look what you did, you made me wander the depths of the OED and the WNT reading about all the cognates of *tharf*, and *dare*. *Dare* is apparently not related to *tharf* but was partly influenced by it. I always thought Dutch durven and English dare were cognates, but no, even despite past forms *dorst* and *durst*, respectively.

Comment: There's a BrE and AmE difference, I think. Modal _need_ or _dare_ are more common in BrE than AmE. In BrE, it is common in negatives and interrogatives - and here we have an instance of the negative.

Comment: Can we use another modal with "need to", " what else can we need to reach our goal?"

Comment: @Özgür: In general, you can use modal verbs with non-modal need (so that is *need to*), but in this example it doesn't sound right. I would just leave out *can* there.

Comment: @PeterShor, German *dürfen* means *to be allowed to* (which in English is often negated as *must not*).

Comment: Note: the _need_ in ‘if need(s) be’ is the noun, not the verb, so that doesn’t really fit in here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ah, so *be* is a subjunctive? I'll remove the example.

Comment: Exactly—there’s even [a question about it](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/128658).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: OK. Done.

Comment: Is there a "Why need ...?" question?

Comment: I thought the regular verb was with s: "He doesn't needs to call he"

Comment: @WeaponX: No, there are several mistakes in that sentence.