# Verb + not = do not verb ? What is the gramatical explanation?

Tags: verbs, word-order, negation, do-support

I have long been puzzled by the usage of 'verb + not'. For example, Kennedy said, "... my fellow Americans, *ask not* what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country." The Bible states, "*Give not* that which is holy unto the dogs, neither cast ye your pearls before swine, lest they trample them under their feet, and turn again and rend you" (Matthew 7:6 KJV).

I think 'verb + not' equals 'do not verb'. Is that so? Can anyone tell me grammatically? 
Is 'verb + not' only used orally? Is it a formal expression or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use "need not" instead of "do not need to"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/why-use-need-not-instead-of-do-not-need-to)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; "You needn't shout" is perfectly ordinary usage; "Shout not" would be unusual.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "verb + not" means the same as "do not + verb." But it is used only in highly formal diction, such as in poetry or oratory. The construction would be very out of place in everyday usage.

Answer (score 3):

It is a stylistic device that puts emphasis on the verb and makes the reader/listener focus in on the statement. It is used in both spoken and written English, but that construction is mainly a rhetorical device for formal speeches and academic/analytical writing.

Answer (score 2):

In earlier times the negation of verbs was simply verb + not.
The use of do/does/did + not/n't is a relatively late development.

The question why to do for negation is justified. Though I can't proof it
I think the reason is the following: in spoken Englisch verb forms + not are contracted. English would get a lot of irregular forms if it would not use to do.
What would be the result of come+n't or came+n't? /kount?/ or /keint?/.

So I think it is a genial invention to use to do and to have only a handful of very frequent contractions. "isn't it" simply is shorter than "does it not be/doesn't it be".

When Kennedy used "ask not... ask" then he used the older system of negation which in rhetoric style can be used in such sentences with antithesis.