# Why do these verbs take bare infinitives?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive, complements, causative-verbs, sense-verbs

> [a] It makes the tree grow. [b] I never heard him speak.

I’m wondering why causative and sense verbs (*make, hear*) license bare infinitives for their complement, instead of taking *to* infinitives? What semantic difference is there between bare and *to* infinitives?

I glimpse a clue that this adjective complement is “more immediately or directly visible (CGEL,p.263)” in ‘she looked **happy**’ than in ‘she looked **to be happy**’; *to* infinitives have meaning of modality, change, and potentiality (CGEL, pp.174, 1242, 1243). And I guess those verbs would take bare infinitives to denote concurrence of matrices and complements' actions. But I’ve not found any accounts of this. Why do they license bare infinitives?

(I've read the difference between their taking infinitive and gerund, in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15158/who-saw-him-die) and CGEL (p.1236-7): the verbs have the "whole event" of the infinitives and "a segment of" the gerund.)

Comment: This is interesting. I've searched and found a chapter in this book *[Pathways of Change: Grammaticalization in English](http://books.google.com/books?id=eUSxewP4KqgC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251)*, "Onginnan/beginnan with bare and to-infitive in AElfric". Possibly related.

Comment: @Susan, I added some words on OP. What I want to know is what's the semantic difference between taking bare-infinitive and to-infinitive.

Comment: Here is part of it, *"The development of Old English verbs capable of taking a bare-infinitival complement is particularly interesting in the light of the general question of the syntactic status of the forerunners of the present-day English auxiliaries. At some stage in the Middle English period lexical verbs can no longer be complemented by a bare infinitive, only by a to-infinitive; the bare infinitive becomes the prerogative of a small set of grammaticalized verbs that have evolved into functional elements with no argument structure of their own."*

Comment: This paper, *[Infinitives in the History of English](http://www.korling.or.kr/est/downfile.php?filename=1958018761525.pdf&filename02=58800686.pdf)* by Hong-Ki Sohng & Seung-Chul Moon, studies the infinitives in VOSI Constructions in the History of English. I skimmed through it a little and think it's even more related to your question than the book I mentioned earlier. For example, they discussed, *"I bet that if you look in the files, you'll find [{that she is/her to be/her} Mexican]."*

Comment: I believe that you can find a clear and thorough answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/11482.

Comment: It's not a simple question, and there may not be any single reason why they license bare infinitives. However, verbs that take bare infinitives include causatives, inchoatives, modals, and sense verbs, at least, and all of these are to a certain extent grammaticalized. I.e, they, as verbs, are bleached of semantic coloring, and represent general rather than specific phemonena; and, in addition, they are party to literally thousands of idioms, frozen forms, irregularities, syntactic constructions, and other grammatical phenomena that are not semantic so much as syntactic.

Comment: A pattern emerges. Probably part of the [Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf) is drawing morphs closer together when they're in construction together, and part of that requires they be shorn of unneeded auxiliaries and markers. Note, for instance, that the _for_ of the _for...to_ infinitive complementizer is regularly dispensed with with [Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), and is required only when  the infinitive begins a sentence (_For me to leave now/*Me to leave now would be a bad idea_).

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95032 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/103662 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/104546

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you very much. I've read what you linked, and it solved the very curiosity I got.

Comment: @Listenever You're very welcome! And thank you too! Your question is thought provoking and really worth pursuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not always thus...see the following http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-23-2/

Answer (score 1):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> It's not a simple question, and there may not be any single reason why they license bare infinitives. However, verbs that take bare infinitives include causatives, inchoatives, modals, and sense verbs, at least, and all of these are to a certain extent grammaticalized. I.e, they, as verbs, are bleached of semantic coloring, and represent general rather than specific phemonena; and, in addition, they are party to literally thousands of idioms, frozen forms, irregularities, syntactic constructions, and other grammatical phenomena that are not semantic so much as syntactic.
>
> A pattern emerges. Probably part of the [Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf) is drawing morphs closer together when they're in construction together, and part of that requires they be shorn of unneeded auxiliaries and markers. Note, for instance, that the *for* of the *for...to* infinitive complementizer is regularly dispensed with with [Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), and is required only when  the infinitive begins a sentence (*For me to leave now/*Me to leave now would be a bad idea*).