# Make us to choose the harder right instead of the easier wrong

Tags: descriptive-grammar

What is "to" doing there in front of "choose"? It's part of West Point's Cadet Prayer.

Comment: Addressed at [Why do these verbs take bare infinitives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144573/why-do-these-verbs-take-bare-infinitives).

Answer (score 1):

This use of the infinitive marker with the verb *make* echoes the sixteenth–seventeenth century Book of Common Prayer of the Church of England, whose archaic forms resonated well into twentieth century Anglican worship. There are still today those who prefer its language.

Her, for example, is the collect (prayer of the day) for the [fourteenth Sunday after Trinity](https://www.pbs.org.uk/the-bcp/fourteenth-sunday-after-trinity):

> Almighty and everlasting God, give unto us the increase of faith, hope and charity; and, that we may obtain that which thou dost promise, *make us to love* that which thou dost command; through Jesus Christ, our Lord. Amen.

The language of the Book of Common Prayer influenced the language of worship of Methodists and other American denominations as well as Lutherans as they abandoned various European languages for English.