# This question popped up on my mind: "why do we use bare infinitives after modal verbs?"

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, bare-infinitive, verb-forms

So, I know that after modal verbs, the bare infinitive or base form of a verb is used according to Oxford ("Modal verbs are followed by the infinitive of another verb without to. The exceptions are ought to, have to and used to.), but why is that? Just got curious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these verbs take bare infinitives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144573/why-do-these-verbs-take-bare-infinitives) [J Lawler gives thoughts on the reason modals and some other verbs license bare infinitives).

Comment: Actually, yes. I didn't see that post, thanks.

Comment: @ZueiraproductionsBr Please note that the verbs are just "ought", "have" and "use"' The "to" is a subordinator, part of the clause that is complement to them, e.g. "I used [to smoke]".