# "He didn't dare [verb]" vs. "He didn't dare *to* [verb]"

Tags: verbs, word-usage, semi-modals

Which one is correct? If both are correct, is there any difference in the meaning?

> He didn't dare **to** contradict his parents.
>
> He didn't dare contradict his parents.

Comment: You might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.

Comment: There's a third valid choice: *"He dared not contradict his parents."*

Comment: This has been [dished here before](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20dare%20need).

Comment: @Peter And a fourth: “He durstn’t [_or_ durst not] contradict his parents”, if you're all right with sounding a bit Victorian and stuffy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That, or backwater-British rustic, maybe somebody whose family hasn’t wandered down out of the highlands for a century or more.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/606455/2085).

Answer (score 1):

*Need* and *dare* are sometimes referred to as *semi-modal* verbs. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103658/are-there-other-verbs-that-work-like-dare-and-need/103662#103662) to a previous question for a good roundup of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

**Both** are correct. In my experience, there is no significant difference in meaning.

I will say that I personally feel like "He didn't dare contradict his parents" sounds more educated, but that's entirely a subjective assessment, and others may feel differently. But neither sounds wrong.

*Note:* When *dare* is used in the imperative (command) form, it is almost *always* used with *to*. So "Dare to try!" will be much more readily understood than "Dare try!" (and some may argue the latter is even incorrect).