# Is the verb auxiliary in "I do"?

Tags: verbs, terminology, yes-no

In the sentence "I do like mint ice cream" 'do' is an auxilliary verb.  However, if you were responding with a "I do" in a wedding vows context, is 'do' auxilliary?  It would be if you continued the line and said "I do promise", but what about when you don't?

Comment: Yes. _Do_ is an auxiliary verb in both situations. The _do_ in _I do like mint ice cream_ is emphatic and therfore stressed. The _do_ in the wedding ceremony is simply a short answer to a question that also uses [_Do_-Support](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299), and it just repeats the auxiliary.

Comment: @JohnLawler - how about you make that an answer?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/362824/77227

Answer (score -1):

When saying 'I do promise', for example, the main verb is -to promise, making the verb -to do an auxiliary, but if just saying 'I do', the only verb used is -to do, being the main verb in the sentence, not having what to assist.

Usually, when 'do' is applied before a verb - as an auxiliary - the strength is highlighted. In the same case, it is possible to use 'I promise', as well as using 'I do promise', what gives the state more confidence.

Comment: No, *I do* is short for *I do take so-and-so as my husband...* or wherever the question was. See [Lawler's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390321/is-the-verb-auxiliary-in-i-do#comment921293_390321)