# Need do Vs need to do

Tags: differences, modal-verbs

I have come across need to do something and need do something. My question is what's the difference between each other? My grammar book doesn't mention it

Comment: The only time I can think of that you would omit the _to_ is in the question form. "Need I ask?" "Need you make so much noise?"

Comment: Agreeing with the above, you might see "need do" in some contexts, particularly less formal ones ("what I need do" gets plenty of Google hits), but "need to do" is always correct, whereas "need do" might sound less formal or incorrect to some.

Comment: I find more places where the "do" gets dropped than where the "to" does.  "Clean your room!" "Do I need to?"

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't *"I need not do something"*? We only drop the *to* in negative sentences.

Comment: @PeterShor has the right of it. When you're finding anomalies in English grammar, look around for negatives. They can change everything. In this case, the negation allows _need_ (a [semi-modal](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/103662/15299)) to act like a true modal auxiliary, and take an infinitive complement without _to_.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use "to do".

'do' is an auxillary, action verb: "*you need **to** do [the thing]*".

I have never hear a native english speaker use the: "*[I need do something.](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/auxiliary-or-helping-verbs/)*" form.

[Auxiliary verbs](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/auxiliary-or-helping-verbs/) add functional or grammatical meaning to the clauses in which they appear. They perform their functions in several different ways:

- By expressing tense ( providing a time reference, i.e. past, present,
  or future)
- Grammatical aspect (expresses how verb relates to the flow
  of time)
- Modality (quantifies verbs) Voice (describes the relationship between the action expressed by the verb and the participants identified by the verb’s subject, object, etc.)
- Adds emphasis to a sentence

Auxiliary verbs almost always appear together with a main verb, and though there are only a few of them (**do**, **be**, and **have** are the main ones), they are among the most frequently occurring verbs in the English language.

Comment: One needn't include the *to* when used in negation.

Comment: "I need not do that..." - quite agree.