# Need and need to

Tags: modal-verbs

Which one of the two sentences - "Do I need mention that she is my wife" or "Do I need to mention that she is my wife" - is correct use.

Comment: May be this will answer your question.

http://english.stackexchange.com/a/103241/139486

Answer (score 0):

Need is a semi-modal verb which can actually follow two patterns:

> Do I need to mention that she is my wife? (treating *need* as a regular verb)

or

> Need I mention that she is my wife? (treating *need* as a modal verb)

Same goes for the negative:

> I don't need to mention...

or

> I needn't mention...

Mixing the two, i.e. using "Do I need mention...?" or "I don't need mention" or "Need I to mention?" is unnatural.

Comment: @GirishBhatnagar that comment almost sounds sarcastic, and rude! You should say "Thank you for answering my trivial question"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think part of the problem here is that, in India (or at least in parts of India), "doubt" means "question". As a result, many uses of "doubt" sound strange or impolite to non-Indians.  (For example, if an American tells me that he has a doubt about one of my theorems, I worry because he thinks he found a mistake; if an Indian says the same thing, I don't worry, because he probably just has a question.)

Comment: Thanks, Andreas!. For clearing Mari-Lou's doubt(!); next time I shall show my gratitude for giving an answer to my question/s.

Answer (score 0):

If the Ngram viewer is any [guide](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need%20mention%2Cneed%20to%20mention&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneed%20mention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20to%20mention%3B%2Cc0), the bare infinitive following "need" used to be more popular than the to-infinitive.  For the bare infinitive, we go from the sublime past, *[The Life and Adventures of Robinson Crusoe](https://books.google.com/books?id=-T_QAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%22need%20mention%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCWoVChMI3va_yOOHyAIVg3I-Ch316guO#v=onepage&q=%22need%20mention%22&f=false)* by Daniel Defoe (1719)

> As to the carpenters, I scarce **need mention** how useful they were.<sup>*</sup>

to the ridiculous modern, *[The Last Job Search Guide You'll Ever Need](https://books.google.com/books?id=fIUp6xoeZywC&pg=PA272&dq=%22need%20mention%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCGoVChMI3va_yOOHyAIVg3I-Ch316guO#v=onepage&q=%22need%20mention%22&f=false/)* by S. J. Rothberg (2002):

> Here, you only **need mention** that you did pet sitting. It doesn't
>   matter that it was for the neighbors or a relative.

*From an 1812 edition published by Chiswick Press