# Is "one needs only" or "one need only" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, negative-polarity-items

This questions concerns the singular or plural form of the word "need". It might concern the property of the word "need" under different circumstances, which consequently affects whether it can inflect normally. Under which circumstance is it considered a catenative verb and which auxiliary verb?

I found both "need" and "needs" have many search results in terms of the phrase "one need/needs only".

For example:

> 1.Should one have any doubts about this proposition, one **need** only look to the perplexing case of Army Specialist Michael New.
>
> 2.But one **needs** only look at Ronsard to realise how much Catullus influenced him.

One is singular, should not need be changed to "needs" as well?
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to ELL.SE. However, I think the point might be that 'one' replaces 'I', and the first-person singular is 'need', not 'needs'.

Comment: what is ELL.SE may I ask? Is it another section of this forum?

Comment: @ShimShay A question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English -- http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, thank you @Kyle, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: I think this question is just fine here. The fact that Jessica B didn't know the answer -- she knew to use *need*, but not the reason why -- is evidence that this question can be of value to native speakers, not just learners.

Comment: @ruakh I guess it depends on how you read the question. My thought was that 'why is this the case?' is relevant here, but the last line made it read as 'which is correct?' which sounds more like ELL.

Comment: @ShimShay: It's at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["need to do" vs "need do"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103230/need-to-do-vs-need-do)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The most common use of *need* is as a regular catenative verb, taking a *to*-infinitive as its complement. In that use, it inflects normally (*need*/*needs*/*needing*/*needed*), can follow an auxiliary verb, and so on: "I might need to talk to him."

However, in a rather formal style of English, there also exists an auxiliary verb ("helping verb") *need*, which is followed by a bare infinitive, and is only used in [negative polarity contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item): with *not*, with *only*, in questions, and so on. Additionally, it only exists in the present tense. Aside from these two restrictions, it's very much like other auxiliary verbs (*can*, *may*, *should*, etc.): "We need not discuss it."

So your first example ("[…] one need only look […]") is correct — using the auxiliary verb *need* — whereas your second example ("[…] one needs only look […]") is wrong — it should either be "one **need** only look" (using the auxiliary verb), or "one only needs **to** look" (using the regular verb).

Another verb that behaves this way, by the way, is *dare*.

Comment: This looks like a very good answer. It really needs supporting quotes from accepted authorities to license this explanation of the two usages of _need_ (and you need to attribute properly).

Comment: If you want I can add cites,as @EdwinAshworth wanted, from CGEL  which has a nice little subchapter 2.5.5 on *Need* and *dare* essentially explaining exactly what you say.

Comment: Ah, I think I've tracked down [where John Lawler addresses the whole issue here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103658/are-there-other-verbs-that-work-like-dare-and-need).