# Unusual Use of Need in Sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

> As for Quinn, there is little that need detain us. Who he was,  where
>   he came from, and what he did are of no great importance.

I was just reading [Paul Auster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Auster)'s [New York Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_York_Trilogy) and came across the sentence above.
I can grasp neither the structure of this sentence nor the meaning quite well, so I have two questions:

1. Is this a valid structure?
2. Whether my following understanding of the sentence is correct:
   We can easily describe Queen and get on with the story.

Any help and references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's valid, and it means "*there is little that **needs to** detain us*", in other words, "*There isn't much that needs to detain us*", or, more simply, "We don't need to wait for anything"..  I'll leave it for someone with more formal knowledge to leave a proper answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "one needs only" or "one need only" correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297233/is-one-needs-only-or-one-need-only-correct). But see John Lawler's answer at [Are there other verbs that work like dare and need?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103658/are-there-other-verbs-that-work-like-dare-and-need) for _the_ answer.

Comment: Yes, you have it essentially right. The complement clause contains "need" as a modal auxiliary verb (expressing necessity) with a bare infinitival clause as complement. A decent paraphrase might be 'There is little necessity to consider Quinn any further'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is nothing there that should keep author and reader from moving on with the story. Since as the following sentence explains, *Who he was, where he came from, and what he did are of no great importance.*

Having a look at need detain, it's pretty straight forward.

*As for Quinn, there is little that need detain us.* It can be rephrased as, *there are not many reasons that make it necessary to be detained at that place in the story.*

The dictionary shows us

> **detain:** Keep (someone) from proceeding by holding them back or **making claims on their attention** [-ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detain)
>
> **need:** [AS MODAL, WITH NEGATIVE OR IN QUESTIONS] **Expressing necessity** or obligation: [-ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/need)