# Use of "need" as modal auxiliary verb

Tags: grammaticality, negative-polarity-items, semi-modals

I have a sentence which is, admittedly, a bit old-fashioned... however, I am wondering if it's a reasonable use of "need" as a modal auxiliary verb

> Note that, because *H* is real and symmetric, we need store only half of the matrix.

I could add "to" between "need" and "store", but to me that feels like a ever-so-slightly different meaning. Adding "to" implies (to me) a kind of absolute necessity, that "we need to do something", while my sentence structure has a bit more of the flavor of "if we store *H*, then we need to store only half..."

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297233/is-one-needs-only-or-one-need-only-correct

Comment: It's related, for sure. Intuitively, "need store only" and "need only store" don't sound equivalent to me -- "need only to store" vs. "need to store only"?

Comment: You mean "we only need to store half the matrix", right? If so, then you are correct in saying that adding "to" implies necessity. The reason is that "need" without "to" is a negative polarity item (i.e. it works only in negative contexts) and "only" makes a negative context. So "We need only store half the matrix" is correct. However, in "We need to store only half the matrix", the scope of the negative context starts with "only"; "need" is outside that context and so implies, as you said, necessity. This sentence implies that you cannot store the full matrix.

Comment: Whether you accept it depends on whether your grammar accepts _only half of the matrix_ as a negative context. If so, fine; if not, ungrammatical. Try it without _only_ to see.

Comment: It seems to me that you “must” store a matrix or some portion thereof for every letter, so it doesn't matter if *need to* sounds bossier than *need only* (which I'm not convinced that it does). *We need store half of the matrix only* sounds about the same as *We need to store half of the matrix only* — to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable. This use of "need" (followed by a bare infinitive) is often called a "pseudo-modal". Other pseudo-modals include "dare", "ought", and "used". They have some, but not all, properties of the typical modal auxiliaries.

Others have suggested that this "need" needs negative polarity, but that isn't always required. For example:

> Do we need to remind you that cheating is forbidden?

can become

> Need we remind you that cheating is forbidden?

You are right that this can seem somewhat old-fashioned, but in some contexts it sounds entirely natural. I find your sentence to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "we need only store half" is a reasonable use of modal "need", licensed by the negativity of "only".

You are right that adding "to" changes the meaning. In fact, for example, "You don't need to go", "You need to not go", and "You need not go" have 3 different meanings.

(I think you probably mean "we need store only half", but what you really mean is up to you.)