# When do we use subjunctive after "unless"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, bare-infinitive, unless

In this sentence:

> The body will not be kept comfortable **unless** the air **be maintained** at a temperature higher than necessary.

Why did the author use "be maintained"?

When do we use subjunctive after "**unless**"?

Comment: It's not a bare infinitive - it's a *subjunctive*. Which would increasingly be changed to ***is** maintained* by contemporary writers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar parsing for "if need be"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128658/grammar-parsing-for-if-need-be)

Comment: But I did not find my answer yet in the link you mentioned. I changed the title to subjunctive as you said. thanks.

Comment: The top answer on the "original" question refers to *a time when ‘if’* (and by implication *'unless'*) *constructions more rigorously required the subjunctive mood in the following verb*. There's nothing else involved here - you're just citing a somewhat dated subjunctive usage. If you need more help understanding this usage, note that ELU is for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps you should ask for clarification on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).