# Modal vs Non-Modal vs Auxiliary modal vs Conjugated Verb

Tags: grammar

Modal vs Non-Modal vs Auxiliary modal vs Conjugated Verb

1. How are these kinds of verb related to each other?
2. Specially Non-Modals and Conjugated Verb.
3. Is the "Auxiliary modal" just another name for "Auxiliary verb"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will give you the traditional definitions, although some other people use slightly different definitions. But I think these are what you are looking for.

A **modal** verb is one that adds information about the probability or desirability of the infinitive that comes with it, like *can, will, must,* etc.

An **auxiliary** verb is one that "supports" another verb, which must be an infinitive or a participle; that is, an auxiliary cannot normally be the only verb in a (main) clause. All modal verbs are normally auxiliary verbs in English. So *must* is modal auxiliary, while *be* is non-modal auxiliary in *I am walking* . Note that *be, do,* and *have* are only auxiliaries in some sentences—not if they do not support an infinitive or participle. So, in *there were two men*, the verb *be* is not auxiliary at all.

A **conjugated** verb is strictly speaking a verb that changes form as the subject changes from singular to plural: the different forms have different endings. So *he walks / they walk*.

There is one problem in English: the endings of the modal verbs, while present in older English and other languages, have been dropped or elided for the present tense in modern English. All modal verbs are traditionally still considered **finite** verbs, even though they have no visible endings any more in the present tense. The reason is that all verbs that aren't infinitives, gerunds, or participles function the same way and should be in the same category, and they must be finite verbs; and modals function just like conjugated verbs. Most of them still get a different form in the past tense, though (*could, would,* etc.) Another criterion by which to recognise a finite verb is that it comes before the subject in direct questions and negations: *he will go there => will he go there?* Non-modal auxiliaries can be finite verbs, participles, or infinitives, but modal auxiliaries can only be finite verbs.

One other category is **copulae**. Verbs that connect a subject with a subject complement are copular, like the verbs *be, become, remain,* etc. So the verb is a copula in *she was angry, they are wolves, he remained a teacher*. So the verb *be* can be auxiliary, copula, or "content word", although opinions differ on when it is which. And some scholars do not recognise all of these distinctions.

Comment: Thank you "Cerebrus and "Barrie England". Please read the following conclusion and see if I am right: Auxiliary verb (parent) ---> 1- Modals (also called auxiliary modal)  2- Semi-modals(Modal Phrase. for example = "Be Able To")  3- Non-Modals(Also called Primary Auxiliary consisting of Do, be, have) 4- copula.

Comment: I would not say that a copular verb was an auxiliary verb, but otherwise  correct in so far as it is possible to summarise a complex matter of grammar in a few lines.

Comment: Hi Barrie.Thank you for your kind answer.I have a question. Some says "need" is a Semi-modal verb. But as far as I know, a Semi-modal verb is consisted of more than one word. Why "need" is a semi-modal verb.

Comment: @long: Thanks! I'm afraid I don't see the mistake, though...?

Comment: @GATA: I agree with Barrie. *Need* can be a modal auxiliary or a regular verb, depending on the construction: *you need not stay* (auxiliary modal; usually with negations); *you need to call her* (regular verb). Note that non-auxiliary verbs that are about probability or desirability are usually not called "modals".

Comment: See for *need* also this question: [Why use “need not” instead of “do not need to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/why-use-need-not-instead-of-do-not-need-to/) About modality in general: [Why do we say “was supposed to” for “should have”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-was-supposed-to-for-should-have/)

Comment: The rules say that I cant use this to say thank you but this time I would feel bad if I don't say it.Thank you very much Cerberus and Barrie.

Comment: @Cerberus. Sorry - I misread. It's early a.m. here. Still +1 for lovely explanantion

Comment: Not all grammars recognise _need_ as a semi-modal verb, but one that does suggests that it is found mainly in British English, and that in general it occurs only in  negatives.

Comment: @Barrie. Thank you. I have one more question and that's that. Please read the following text :  "Microsoft CEO Steve Ballmer is planning his retirement in the next nine months from the software giant he helped build". Is "helped" a non-modal verb here. If yes then would you please tell me how you recognize it as a non-modal?

Comment: You might like to make that a new question.

Comment: I did it :)  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138053/help-as-a-non-modal-verb

Answer (score 7):

There are two kinds of auxiliary verb, primary and modal. The primary auxiliary verbs are *be, have* and *do*. The modal auxiliary verbs are *can, may, might, could, would, will, shall, must* and *should*. *(Had) better, have to, (have) got to, ought to, be supposed to, be going to* and *used to* are semi-modal verbs.

All verbs except the modal verbs, and some of the semi-modals, conjugate. That means they change their form to indicate tense and person. *Walk*, for example, becomes *walks* after *he* and *she* in the present tense, and *walked* in the past tense. *Be* becomes *is* after *he, she* and *it* in the present tense and, in the past tense, *was* after *I* and *he, she* and *it* and *were* after *you, we* and *they*.

Comment: Where 'is to/are to' that is " be+ to" be grouped?